# SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' When installing PyCharm Package

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to import various packages (one being PyGObject but I've tried others), and I'm getting an error when PyCharm is trying to install the package.

`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`

I've tried to use pip by entering `pip -m install PyGObject` in the Command Line, but I'm getting an error there as well:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>pip -m install BeautifulSoup
  File "<stdin>", line 1
  install BeautifulSoup
                      ^
```

I am new to Python, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I have Python 3.5.4

Comment: Is that command line or a python interpreter? The traceback seems to indicate you put it in the interpreter.

Comment: I think to install BeautifulSoup you can do by installing bs4 package: `!pip install bs4` and using by `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I tried using Pycharm first and then I tried in command line

Comment: I just tried bs4 and that worked, although I'm still getting an issue with PyGObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have Python 3.5.4

Perfect! Keep using python3.

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

In python2, `print 2` is valid. In python3, one must phrase it `print(3)`. The syntax error suggests you imported a python2-only module.

Please refer to [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> $ pip install beautifulsoup4
>
> (The BeautifulSoup package is probably not what you want. That’s the previous major release, ...

It looks like you specified `BeautifulSoup`, which is the downrev version 3. You'd be happier following their recommendation and then using `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

If you still have "an issue with PyGObject", that sounds like a topic for a separate SO Question.

Comment: I found that out :) What about PyGObject? Is that only for Python 2?

Comment: PyGObject is the library I want to install